# "Approximately equal" between Sync and Async operations for PageCleaners

Tags: performance, db2, buffer-pool

The documentation of `num_iocleaners` says:

> The parameter can be reduced if both of the following conditions are true:
>
> - pool_data_writes is approximately equal to pool_async_data_writes
> - pool_index_writes is approximately equal to pool_async_index_writes.
>
> The parameter should be increased if either of the following conditions are true:
>
> - pool_data_writes is much greater than pool_async_data_writes
> - pool_index_writes is much greater than pool_async_index_writes.

What is approximately? What is "much greater"?  What ratio?  What percentage of difference?

Does anyone have an example of values that are "approximately equal" and where the `Page Cleaners` value should be increased? The same info for the "much geater" values would also be appreciated.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000332.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-4-4-8-108&lang=en

Comment: I have a database with: Asynchronous pool data page reads          = 1061292948 and Buffer pool data writes                    = 21701013. I think that is "much greater than". Am I right?

Comment: What's the value for async pool data page *writes* ?

Comment: Problem when selecting from the snapshot. Here the values: Buffer pool data writes                    = 21708727
Asynchronous pool data page writes         = 20343761

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you want as many of your writes as possible to be asynchronous. On the other hand, `pool_data_writes` will always be greater than `pool_async_data_writes` (ditto for index writes).

The tolerance depends entirely on your system. If each minute you have 3 `pool_data_writes` and only 1 `pool_async_data_writes`, you obviously have twice as many synchronous writes as you have asynchronous, but it's hardly a reason for concern.

If, on the other hand, each minute you have 300K `pool_data_writes` and 290K `pool_async_data_writes`, the difference appears to be minor, but you still have 10000/60 ~ 166 waits per second, which is pretty bad.

Please keep in mind that `num_iocleaners` is not the only configuration parameter that affects the write efficiency: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0011381.html?lang=en

PS. In your comment you compare *asynchronous reads* with *writes*, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you said. However, how can I create a formula to verify the values? I have many databases with different configuration, and I would like to see if there is a problem with all of them. I cannot check one by one. I would like to create a Nagios script that checks that but I need a formula or method to raise an error. Actually, the num_iocleaners is static in most of the databases, and I need to identify where this fixed value is impacting the performance.

Comment: The formula you probably want to look at is the number of synchronous buffer pool writes per second.  You will want to monitor for when that goes over a certain threshold and then tune based on that (whether its IO Cleaners, buffer pool size, etc.).